# BottomNavigatioView ColorStateList not work on api <=26

Tags: android, kotlin, selector, drawable, bottomnavigationview

I have integrated the bottomNavigationView into my app. I have configured some ColorStateList to change the background color. This selector is ignored in api <= 26

This is my Background selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#B59339" android:drawable="@color/gold" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#112620" android:drawable="@color/app_dark_color" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And this is my bottomNavigationView

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_tint"
app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_tint"
```

I've also tried using drawables, but it doesn't change anything

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_tint"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_tint"
```

Comment: They are ColorStateList

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ok, edited. do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: The selector should be something like:
`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="..." android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="...."/>
</selector>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved.
I moved the colorFilterList file into drawable and called it like this:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_background"
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_tint"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_tint"
```